# How to return Future or any other types from a function in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to handle the back button press on one of my Form entry widgets. This is how I implemented the WillPopScope's onWillPop method :

```
Future<bool> _onWillPop() {
    if (changed) {
       return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
              title: new Text('Save'),
              content: new Text("Do you want to save the changes?"),
              actions: <Widget>[
                new FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                  child: new Text('No'),
                ),
                new FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                    saveMeeting();
                  },
                  child: new Text('Yes'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
      ) ??
      false;
    } else {
      print("No changes");
      Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
      //return some future null from here ????
    }
}
```

This part of the code is working but getting an exception:

```
[ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 7374): Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null
```

How can I implement this correctly?

Comment: Reason for the error is, you are not returning bool value outside `if` or inside `else`

Comment: I tried with returning true, but the IDE says it expects Future<bool>, not a bool type.

Comment: why did you use if condition

Comment: I need to display an alert on pressing the back button. If the user made any changes to the data, the changed will become true and at that time only I need to display the alert.

Comment: @KrishnathkumarCN you dont have to do that , it will take care of onWillPop I have added an example, check it out and if its worked for you, please vote and make it the correct answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Import "dart:async" package,
and add async keyword to your method signature like

```
Future<bool> _onWillPop() async{
```

After this, you will just need to return a boolean value whenever your method completes its processing just like any other function

Comment: Your error message"Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null" may mean the boolean variable you are using in "if" condition is null, so please check if "changed" variable is not null before using it in "if" condition or add "changed != null" condition in your "if" clause

Answer (score 53):

I had exactly the same problem.

I solved it by returning Future.value(false); If the value is true I get the black screen.

```
Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
 if (!widget.editing) {
   Navigator.pop(context, true);
   return Future.value(false);
 } else {
   return showDialog(...
```

Comment: `Future.value()` which saved my day. Thanks @csigueros

Answer (score 1):

> Your comment: I need to display an alert on pressing the back button.
>   If the user made any changes to the data, the changed will become true
>   and at that time only I need to display the alert.

You don't have to check for that.

You can refer below example(from official material examples, [here you can see a complete example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/text_form_field_demo.dart)) and get some idea:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

bool _formWasEdited = false;

final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

Future<bool> _warnUserAboutInvalidData() async {
    final FormState form = _formKey.currentState;
    if (form == null || !_formWasEdited || form.validate())
      return true;

    return await showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('This form has errors'),
          content: const Text('Really leave this form?'),
          actions: <Widget> [
            new FlatButton(
              child: const Text('YES'),
              onPressed: () { Navigator.of(context).pop(true); },
            ),
            new FlatButton(
              child: const Text('NO'),
              onPressed: () { Navigator.of(context).pop(false); },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ) ?? false;
  }
```

And in the `Form` widget:

```
child: new Form(
    key: _formKey,
    autovalidate: _autovalidate,
    onWillPop: _warnUserAboutInvalidData,
    //........
```